# How to compile Rust code to exe from a linux machine

Tags: rust, compilation, cross-compiling

This is my first time learning Rust, and I'm thinking about how can I compile my Rust code to .exe as I'm using Ubuntu. Btw, this is also the first low-level language I'm learning, as I came from Python and JavaScript background, and I'm still new to this compiling concept.
Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: Thanks, but I also saw this one and noticed it's 6 years ago. So I wonder if it's still relevant?

Comment: From my personal experience, it's still quite relevant. If something doesn't work for you, you always can ask more specific question with concrete problem.

Comment: While the question is 6 years old, the accepted and most upvoted answer is from last year. Yes, things have changed in 6 years, but not since last year, and probably won't change anymore, the solution described being basically as simple as one can expect cross compilation to be.

Comment: What stopped you from trying?